# How to remote execute an ELEVATED remote script in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting, elevated-privileges

I have two servers:

- **serverA** (windows 2003 server)
- **serverB** (windows 7)

**ServerA** contains a folder with a batch file (deploy.bat) that needs to be executed from an elevated powershell prompt. In **ServerA**, if I run it from a normal prompt or powershell prompt it fails. If I run it from an elevated prompt it works. (run as administrator).

The problem I have is when I try to execute batch file from **serverB** using a remote powershell execution. I am able to execute with this command:

```
Invoke-Command -computername serverA .\remotedeploy.ps1
```

The content of  **remotedeploy.ps1** is:

```
cd D:\Builds\build5
.\Deploy.bat
```

I have looked a lot questions in stackoverflow about:

- Execute a remote powershell (This works for me)
- Execute a local powershell with elevated prompt (I can do it)

This question is about both at the same time. So the exact question is:

**Is possible to execute an ELEVATED REMOTE script in PowerShell?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try to change `remoteDeploy.ps1` to start CMD.EXE with elevated rights :

```
cd D:\Builds\build5
start-process CMD.EXE -verb runas -argumentlist "-C",".\Deploy.bat"
```

Comment: I think I have tried this but asked me for a password (not an option as I need it to run in a build script) and seem there is no option for putting a password. 
I will try again now just to be sure.

Comment: It doesn't work. When executing it locally a windows form prompt asking me permission and when I remote execute it, freezes because of same windows form prompt I guess.

Comment: It seems to work form me, but I use the real admin credentials, when I create my PSSession.

Comment: What are you using in deploy.bat that need to be elevated. The program should not use UI.

Comment: I am using a SQLCompare tool.  I have managed to stop needing elevated permissions. 
The UI that appear is the "runas" UI asking me to confirm if I want to run process with elevated permissions.

Comment: @cad if this didn't work, why'd you accept the answer?

Comment: It's answered the question, as far as I understand @]cad's problem comes from UI.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PowerShell 4, you can execute the command using Desired State Configuration, which run as `SYSTEM`:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerA -ScriptBlock {
    configuration DeployBat
    {
        # DSC throws weird errors when run in strict mode. Make sure it is turned off.
        Set-StrictMode -Off

        # We have to specify what computers/nodes to run on.
        Node localhost 
        {
            Script 'Deploy.bat'
            {
                # Code you want to run goes in this script block
                SetScript = {
                    Set-Location 'D:\Builds\build5'
                    # DSC doesn't show STDOUT, so pipe it to the verbose stream
                    .\Deploy.bat | Write-Verbose
                }

                # Return $false otherwise SetScript block won't run.
                TestScript = { return $false }

                # This must returns a hashtable with a 'Result' key/value.
                GetScript = { return @{ 'Result' = 'RUN' } }
            }
        }
    }

    # Create the configuration .mof files to run, which are output to
    # 'DeployBot\NODE_NAME.mof' directory/files in the current directory. The default 
    # directory when remoting is C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents.
    DeployBat

    # Run the configuration we just created. They are run against each NODE. Using the 
    # -Verbose switch because DSC doesn't show STDOUT so our resources pipes it to the 
    # verbose stream.
    Start-DscConfiguration -Wait -Path .\DeployBat -Verbose
}
```